# XSLT 2.0 remove element only from first record

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have placed my XSLT code in below  (click below link)

[code](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXn/5)

My expected output is :

```
<InputParameters>
 <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000365-1002-M</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528224</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534647</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000328</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>Component Of</nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528229</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534648</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000327</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>Component Of</nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528239</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
    </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
</InputParameters>
```

i.e.  Remove below elements only in first record but retain in others

```
<nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF/>
<nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE/>
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the requirement stated so far only as the expected output and the description "remove below elements only in the first record"? The code you have linked to uses grouping, is the requirement "first record" related to the grouping? Anyway, if you really want your empty templates to remove some elements only be applied when processing certain nodes like the "first record" then I think you should use two different modes and push the "first record" through the modes that has the empty templates to remove the two elements and the other "records" through a mode copying all.

Comment: Thanks Martin  could you please assist me here (I'm new to XSLT) like how to pass to two different modes. I'm providing the link here having my code and input -> https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXn/5   .   I want to remove the elements in first record and keep as is in other records